# How to animate cloud icon in a SVG image

Tags: css, svg, css-animations, svg-animate

I am new to svg animation.
I am trying to animate the clouds which is there in the svg image. But its not working as expected  I want all the cloud should from their position and start moving to the end of the image and repeats continuously but its not happening.
Here is my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/tuneof2f/)

Code I used to animate:

```
<animateTransform attributeName="transform" from="1100" to="0" type="translate" begin="5s" dur="18s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
```

Comment: What exactly isn't happening? I see what you described as expected in Chrome on OS X.

Comment: Cloud is not start moving from its place. Now its starting from the cornor of the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems to be working fine.

However, if you want the animation to start immediately, you should specify a negative `begin` attribute. Also, the `from` and `to` coordinates are both within the `viewBox` range, so instead of sliding off the left side of the picture and back in at the right side (which is what I assume you want), the clouds are suddenly teleporting across the picture when they get close to the left side.

**EDIT:** I just spotted another problem — you're supposed to provide two values for `translate` attributes. You only provided one, which is why all the clouds are sitting on the same horizontal line.

Changing the attributes as follows should fix these issues (assuming you want a Y coordinate of 123):

```
<animateTransform
    attributeName="transform"
    from="1700 123"
    to="-500"
    type="translate"
    begin="-5s"
    dur="18s"
    repeatCount="indefinite"
/>
```

[Here's an updated jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/tuneof2f/2/)

> P.S: Next time you have a problem like this, start by making a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and post it here using the snippet editor. You'll be much more likely to get help that way.